# Group by and then order within groups in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Let's assume a list of objects with two properties - `int` `Val1` and `double` `Val2`. I want to group it by `Val1`, and then order within groups by `Val2`.

Example list:

```
Val1 Val2
1    2.4
2    1.3
1    1.9
2    5.1
```

Properly grouped and ordered list would look like:

```
Val1 Val2
1    1.9
1    2.4
2    1.3
2    5.1
```

The first thing that comes to my mind is using LINQ.

```cs
list = list.GroupBy(x => x.Val1).SelectMany(x => x).OrderBy(x => x.Val2).ToList();
```

But results are not correct - `OrderBy` entirely overrides `GroupBy`.

Approach with different order of methods almost works:

```cs
list = list.OrderBy(x => x.Val2).GroupBy(x => x.Val1).SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```

But `Val1` are reversed - go from higher to lower value, while `Val2` is ordered correctly. Can't just reverse list, since it would reverse `Val2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to group it by Val1, and then order within groups by Val2.

I think you want something else: you want to order the list by `Val1` and then by `Val2`:

```
list = list
    .OrderBy(x => x.Val1)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Val2)
    .ToList();
```

It doesn't make sense to create groups and then flatten them if all you want is ordering.